# Addin Not working in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, add-in, trimble

I'm trying to configure Positions Desktop AddIn (v10.5.0.2) with Esri ArcMap(10.4.1) for the first time yet not having any luck. The Positions single use license is activated and the software is showing as installed on my computer.

In ArcMap I navigated to Customize-> Add-In Manager->Customize->Add from File... then select the Positions AddIn from my hard drive folder location.

Once doing so I get the error message prompted from ArcMap(See attached Picture). Does anyone know if I'm doing some wrong with the configuration for this AddIn? How do I resolve this issue? I couldn't find any literature from Trimble stating compatibility issues with (v10.5.0.2)
[image]

Comment: I found this on the Trimble documentation, it might be worth a try:
Make sure the Trimble Positions Desktop add-in is allowed to be loaded:
a. Start Esri ArcGIS Desktop, click Customize / Add-In Manager..., click the Options tab, and then select Require Add-Ins to be digitally signed by a trusted publisher.
Click Close.
b. Click Customize / Add-In Manager..., and then click the Add-Ins tab. The Trimble Positions Desktop add-in should now appear in the list. Click Close.
c. Click Customize / Extensions..., and select Trimble Positions Desktop to enable it
for use. Click Close.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to load an AddIn compiled for ArcGIS 10.5 in ArcGIS 10.4. This is not supported. You'll need to update your ArcGIS version to ArcGIS 10.5 or higher. Higher ArcGIS versions normaly can handle older AddIn versions.